# Permissions of parent directories when bind mounting to child directories in Docker

Tags: docker, permissions

Let's say I have a directory structure on my host: `/home/user/project`. In this project directory I have all my project  - sources, etc. Among the directories in project, I have `build` directory.

I want to run a docker container with the following bind mount:

```
$ docker run -v /home/user/project/build:/tmp/build ...
```

Now I want in the container to be able to write to the project directory. But I notice that, the permissions on the `build` directory is the same as the host, but the permissions on the parent directory - `project` - is `drwxr-xr-x`

Why is this, and how should I deal with this?

Comment: Can you `COPY` the application into the image, without the bind mount?  Can you store the application data somewhere other than the build directory?

Comment: No, I can't. I didn't want to specify all the background to this issue, but from a technical point of view what I've described is exactly what I need.